# Make [jena] and [apache-jena] synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

*(I know that there's a tag synonym voting system, but it doesn't appear to do much (looking for examples, I found [Does the tag synonym suggestion system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127459/does-the-tag-synonym-suggestion-system-work)).)*

I have [suggested the synonym in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jena/synonyms), but it's a relatively low traffic tag.  The [jena](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jena) tag has 1389 questions, [apache-jena](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-jena) has 88.  Part of the reason that there are so few [apache-jena](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-jena) questions is that they quickly get retagged with [jena](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jena) much of the time.  The description for [apache-jena](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-jena) says "This is a synonym for the Jena tag.", but they've got different info pages, so I think that means "an informal synonym."  Looking through [the edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28655041/revisions), it appears that people have tried to indicate that [apache-jena](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-jena) is unneeded in the past, too.